# Co-ordinates of the point on a sphere which is closest & furthest to another point

Tags: calculus

I just need some help with this question.

Let  be the sphere of radius 2 centred at the origin. Find the co-ordinates of the point on  which is closest to and furthest to the point with co-ordinates (1,2√2,4).

Lagrange multipliers is preferred. I have a rough idea how to go about this question but would just like some clarification.

What I have so far is f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4 And also g(x,y,z) = (x-1)^2+(y-2√2)^2 + (z-4)^2

Then from there I've used the lagrange multiplier and gotten values, i.e.

2(x-1) = 2xλ

2(y-2√2) = 2yλ

2(x-4) = 2zλ

Am I on the right track? If so, I don't know how to complete it

Comment: The closest and farthest points will lie on the line through the origin and $(1,2\sqrt{2},4)$

Comment: You have already asked this exact question. This should be closed. Link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4123223

Comment: Seeing the link shared by @311411. I see you already edited the previous question with your effort. Then why did you repost? Please delete one of the questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geometrically, can you see why the closest or farther point on surface $S$ to point $P(1, 2\sqrt2, 4)$ will be on the line segment $OP$ where $O$ is origin?

$|OP| = 5$. So unit vector in the direction of $OP$ is $ \ \frac{1}{5}(1, 2\sqrt2, 4)$. As radius $|r| = 2$, the point of surface $S$ which is closest to $P$ is $\ \frac{2}{5}(1, 2\sqrt2, 4)$ and farthest to $P$ is $\ -\frac{2}{5}(1, 2\sqrt2, 4)$.

Using Lagrange Multiplier method,

$2(x-1) = 2 x \lambda \implies \lambda = \frac{x-1}{x}, x \ne 0$

Plugging in value of $\lambda$ in

$2(y - 2\sqrt2) = 2y \lambda, y = 2\sqrt2x$

and in $2(z - 4\sqrt2) = 2z \lambda, z = 4x$

Plugging in values of $y, z$ into constraint $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 4$, you get two points $ \pm (\frac{2}{5}, \frac{4\sqrt2}{5}, \frac{8}{5})$ (same as earlier).

Comment: Yes I can see why the point will be on the line segment OP, but can I ask then, is my g(x,y,z) = (x-1)^2+(y-2√2)^2 + (z-4)^2 ... correct? Or should the squares be removed to resemble a plane?

Comment: You have taken square of distance and that is fine. If the square of distance is max or min, so will be the distance. As you can see, it gives the correct result.